# If $A$ is a normal matrix, can we say that $A^{H}$ is also normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As title, my question is: given that $A$ is a normal matrix, then can we say that $A^H$ which is a Hermitian $A$ is also normal.

My attempt is that:
If $A$ is normal, then we know that $A^HA=AA^H$.

Now, if we replace $A$ by $A^H$, then we can get the same result that $AA^H=A^HA$.

So, we can conclude that if $A$ is normal, then so is its Hermitian.

May I know if I am correct or make any mistakes in my attempt?

Thanks for reading and commenting.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

We have:
$$\left(A^H\right)^H=A$$

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your attempt is not yet correct. You must prove that $B=A^H$ is normal by definition, meaning that $BB^H = B^HB$. In your case, you must prove that $$A^H(A^H)^H = (A^H)^H A^H.$$
Using hints from other answers should show this equality fairly quickly.

Comment: In the question is says "Now, if we replace $A$ by $A^H$, then we can get the same result that $AA^H=A^HA$." Note that is not the exact same equation as the initial one, the exponents $H$ have moved. I take this for evidence that OP already did before asking the question what you suggest (s)he should do. (There is just the somewhat mysterious "can" in the sentence, without which it would be entirely clear, but I don't think it means a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely correct, and pretty obvious given that $A^{HH}=A$.

Comment: I don't think it is correct. For one thing, he does not say that $A^{HH}=A$ which is a vital part of what he is trying to prove. Also, he seems to claim that $AA^H=A^HA$ is the *exact* equation that must hold for $A^H$ to be normal, which is technically not true.

Comment: @5xum What OP says implies that $A^{HH}=A$ _was used_. Indeed the fact that an obviously equivalent but not identical equation was obtained is evidence for that. Of course OP could have been clearer about what was done here, but I cannot see much other options than that $A^H$ was substituted for $A$ and then $A^{HH}$ replaced by $A$.

Comment: True, you are most probably correct. Still, since the statement proven is very simple, I would demand a student to at least mention he used $A^{HH}=A$ in his proof.

Comment: @Marc, 5xum Thank you for your comments and I have learned how to present the proof clearly through your comments. Really thz a lot.:)